# Javascript checking if image is in the array

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to simplify some code and I have 4 variables that hold an array of images and finally there is a final one called cards that holds all 4 variables.

The other part of it generates a random image from the cards and changes a canvas in html.

Now what I am trying to do, which is what I need help on, is to use an if statement to see if the image generated is from either one of the 4 variables and if so I want it to change a value to make it obvious that it has worked.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**HTML**

```
<button class="open" onclick="pack100()">Open &#163;250 Cards.</button>
<div class=card-group>
    <img class="card" src="http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/blank.png" id="cp1" />
    <p>Worth: &#163;<span id="w1">0</span></p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var bronze = new Array("http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/a.k.a.bronze.jpg");
var silver = new Array("http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/ssgsilver.jpg");
var gold = new Array("http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/a.w.p.gold.jpg");
var legends = new Array("http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/karambitee.jpg");
var cards = new Array(bronze, silver, gold, legends);
var cash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
function pack100(){
    if (Number(cash) >= 250){
        var profit = 0;
        cash = cash - 250;
        var c1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
        document.getElementById("cp1").src = cards[c1];
        var cp1 = document.getElementById('cp1').src;
        if (cp1 == gold){
            profit += 50;
            document.getElementById("w1").innerHTML = 500000000000000000000;
            document.getElementById("profit").innerHTML = 500000000000000;
        };
```

Comment: `in_array()` function can help you. It's implemented in javascript with php syntax: http://locutusjs.io/php/array/in_array/

Comment: why do you create all these single-element-Arrays?

Comment: Why are you creating a new array with only one item, and then creating a new array from all those single item arrays?

Comment: Why are `bronze`, `silver` etc arrays and not plain strings? You're using them as strings (`cp1 == gold` instead of `cp1 == gold[0]`), but I imagine you'd be better off having them as strings.

Comment: When I make more images they will go into the corresponding array, so I can shorten the code in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand, It works correctly. Be careful to close the if statement and the function, but it works. To make it obvious that it has changed you can put `alert("your message")`.

One thing tho, instead of using arrays of 1 element, use strings, it's more undertandable.

I wrote an HTML page with this and it works, i just changed cash variable because you didn't gave us the element with `id = cash`. There are some images with broken links, so it wont show the image. Here it is:

```
<html>
<header>
    </header>
<body>
<button class="open" onclick="pack100()">Open &#163;250 Cards.</button>
<div class=card-group>
    <img class="card" src="http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/blank.png" id="cp1" />
    <p>Worth: &#163;<span id="w1">0</span></p>
</div>

<script>
var bronze = "http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/a.k.a.bronze.jpg";
var silver = "http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/ssgsilver.jpg";
var gold = "http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/a.w.p.gold.jpg";
var legends = "http://tacticalcards.esy.es/images/karambitee.jpg";
var cards = new Array(bronze, silver, gold, legends);
var cash = 350;
function pack100(){
    alert("works");
    if (Number(cash) >= 250){
        var profit = 0;
        cash = cash - 250;
        var c1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
        document.getElementById("cp1").src = cards[c1];
        var cp1 = document.getElementById('cp1').src;
        if (cp1 == gold){
            alert("gold");
            profit += 50;
            document.getElementById("w1").innerHTML = 500000000000000000000;
            document.getElementById("profit").innerHTML = 500000000000000;
        }
    }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cards` array there are 4 "card types". If I got your question correctly, you're picking a random type using a random index:

```
var c1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
```

`c1` now holds a number (in your example, a number between 0 and 3). To check the type that corresponds to this number, you **cannot** do:

```
if (c1 == gold) { /* ... */ }
```

This compares a `number` to an `array`. Instead, you'll have to do:

```
if (cards[c1] === gold) { /* ... */ }
```

This checks if the `array` inside `cards` at index `c1` is *the same* array as the `gold` array.

Comment: You also have to set the `src` attribute differently. I tried to explain how stuff works my answer; I wasn't giving you the full code you can copy paste to fix everything. To set the `src` you need to specify another index: e.g.: `document.getElementById("cp1").src = cards[c1][0]`